# Failed to queue any items

Tags: ios, objective-c

When I quit `MPMoviePlayerViewController`,
The console prompt "*Failed to queue any items*",
Every time!
I just play a video for **URL**

Comment: Pls update question with some code.

Comment: There is no other custom code,I'm just initialization `MPMoviePlayerViewController` ,  
 `MPMoviePlayerViewController *vc = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];`  But when I quit, The console prompt "Failed to queue any items".